# How to create controls based on the backend response in sapui5?

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I want to generate a UI based on backend data provided in a service.

My Service will look like below:

```
    {
    "ControlData": {
        "results": [{
            "Label": "Gender?",
            "Type": "COMBOBOX"
        }],
        "ControlValues": {
            "results": [{
                    "Key": "M",
                    "Value": "Male"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "F",
                    "Value": "Female"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here I want to generate a ComboBox control with label and values provided in the service dynamically.

Please provide me any example or reference to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use factory functions

[Using Factory Functions](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/335848ac1174435c901baaa55f6d7819)

[Step 15: Aggregation Binding Using a Factory Function](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/284a036c8ff943238fb65bf5a2676fb7)